# Alternative of ORDER BY in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hadoop-streaming

By using ORDER BY in hive, It only uses single reducer. So ORDER BY is inefficient. Is there any alternative solution available for ORDER BY.

Regards,
Ratto

Answer (score 4):

You will probably want to use the combination of DISTRIBUTE BY and SORT BY.  DISTRIBUTE BY will ensure that all keys with a certain value will end up on the same data node.  SORT BY will then sort the data on each node.

For Example:

```
SELECT a, b, c 
FROM table
DISTRIBUTE by a
SORT BY a, b
```

ORDER BY will sort **all** of the data together, which is why it has to pass through one reducer.

Answer (score 0):

[SORT BY](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy) should do the trick.  This will sort the data within each reducer, so the values for a given key will be in order, but the keys are not guaranteed to be in order.  You can use any number of reducers for SORT BY.